# Cannot replace dynamic finder with .where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In a sessions controller I'm unsuccessfully trying to replace a ".find_by_email(params[:email])" with .where(email: params[:email]), and validating the password with Rails built-in has_secure_password. While the former works, the latter results in a caught exception:

```
undefined method `authenticate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000010384e690>
```

This is the complete code in the controller that doesn't work:

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

```
def create
  user = User.where(email: params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to texts_path, notice: "Logged in!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authenticate` is an instance method of the `User` class, however `where` returns an assortment of these objects within an ActiveRecord::Relation which doesn't know about this method. That code previously worked with the `find_by_email` method as that returns a single User object. To fix you can change this line:

```
user = User.where(email: params[:email])
```

to:

```
user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make a very small change

```
user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
```

As Cyle mentioned, you need a single element, not the array returned by where.